# How to add a Combobox or browse option in one particular row of a grid control using CMFCPropertyGridProperty class

Tags: c++, mfc, gridcontrol

I have Property Grid Control in which i have to add different controls in each of the rows, like Combo box, Browse option, Radio option etc. I am using `CMFCPropertyGridProperty` class to add the string to this controls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `CMFCPropertyGridProperty::AddOption()` to add options. The set of options is internally implemented based on Combo Box.

If you'd like to add file/folder browse options you have to do the following:

```
// A folder browse dialog property
CMFCPropertyGridFileProperty* pFolderProp = new CMFCPropertyGridFileProperty(_T("Select folder"), _T("C:\\Windows"));
m_PropGridCtrl.AddSubItem( pFolderProp );

// A file open dialog property
CMFCPropertyGridFileProperty* pFileProp = new CMFCPropertyGridFileProperty(_T("Select file"), TRUE, _T("C:\\Windows"));
m_PropGridCtrl.AddSubItem( pFileProp );
```

Comment: I am able to add the Combo and the Browse options but couldn't find adding a check box. Any suggestions ? Thanks

Comment: You have to implement it yourself. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/4043c308-f57a-48c4-acb8-2c9de93f429a/cmfcpropertygridproperty-lokalisierung?forum=visualcplusde